# PHP 7.1 on OS X 10.15.1 Catalina and PHP 7.3 on Brew conflict

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

I've OSX Catalina and I have just updated PHP by Brew

> brew upgrade php

and if I do * php -v*  I get

> PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul 16 2019 16:30:30) ( NTS )

But if I run composer to install a package it returns this error:

> This package requires php ^7.2 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.

Why Iget this error if I'm using php 7.3?

I've also installed Mamp but I don't think it is the issue.  Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My gut instinct tells me you might have multiple php installations, and composer is looking at one that's not the 7.3